# How to enter multiple email ids in angularjs form field?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I want a form field in angularjs form such that I can enter multiple email ids separated by commas and they get updated in the $scope object in array form.
For eg. in form field i entered email ids: ads@gmail.com, aman@gmail.com, qaz@yahoo.com
Now in my $scope variable(say '$scope.emails'), i want them to be updated like ["ads@gmail.com", "aman@gmail.com", "qaz@yahoo.com"] to POST the form.
I am beginner in angularjs and stucked at this stage. Please help me to get out of this situation.

Comment: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/demo-multiple-selection.html

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan , thanks for your response but i don't need to select email ids from drop down. I need to enter the email ids manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can

1. bind the form field value(ng-model) as something like `$scope.emailField`.
2. use `ng-blur` to bind a function on the scope to parse the value of `$scope.emailField` (split by comma)
3. assign the result array back to your `$scope.emails`.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. what can i do if i want to check the validation of emails ids at the same time?

Comment: @AmandeepSachan, Then you can define a corresponding **regex** and use the angular's built-in `ng-pattern` directive on the input field to get the true/false from the `$scope.emailField.$valid` and display your own custom error message to user.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ng-tags-input](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/) for this purpose

or use this code

```
return text.split(",");
```

in ng-model setter getter or on any events

Answer (score 0):

I think @Leon li's solution is a good one, but to add an alternative, you can use REGEX to process the field's input before sending it to the server.

```
/\s*(?:([a-z0-9.!#$%&’*+=?^_`{|}~-]+@(?:[a-z0-9-]+\.){1,3}(?:[a-z0-9-]+)(?::[0-9]+)?))\s*/gi
```

That expression will accept pretty much any kind of email, and each match will be put into its own matching group. You would then process it like so:

```
function processEmails (fieldValue)
{
  var output = [];
  var match = fieldValue.match (emailRegex);

  if (!match)
  {
    //No emails entered. Handle error here
  }
  else
  {
    //The first index (0) is not a matching group
    for (var i = 1; i < match.length; i++)
    {
      output.push (match[i]);
    }
  }

  return output;
}
```

To test: https://regex101.com/r/glZrjC/1

Comment: @DominicAcquilina  Thanks for your kind suggestion.